# Save function argument as character

Tags: r, dataframe, character

I want to save the argument of a function as a variable in r.
I've tried deparse, but on a dataframe it returns the wrong thing. Below is what I want.

```r
dataframe <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 3), b=c(3, 6, 8))

afunction <- function(arg1, arg2) {
  arg1_character <- deparse(arg1)
  arg2_character <- deparse(arg2)
}

afunction(a ~ b, dataframe)
```

Based on this simple example I'd want the following output:

```r
arg1_character <- "a~b"
arg2_character <- "dataframe"
```

Comment: why should it return `x~y`?

Comment: I am trying to create a class, where I want to be able to use `class$call` to show what the call of the function was. Edit, I see it says "x~y", it should be "a~b". My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `deparse(substitute())`.

```
afunction <- function(arg1, arg2) {
  arg1_character <- deparse(substitute(arg1))
  arg2_character <- deparse(substitute(arg2))
  c(arg1_character, arg2_character)
}

afunction(a ~ b, dataframe)
# [1] "a ~ b"     "dataframe"
```

Or try `match.call()`

```
afunction2 <- function(arg1, arg2) {
  cat('Call:\n')
  match.call()
}
afunction2(a ~ b, dataframe)
# Call:
# afunction2(arg1 = a ~ b, arg2 = dataframe)
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do it!! Out of curiosity, would there be a way to concatenate these with "Call"? So you get something like the lm() calls?

Comment: @OLGJ Something like `cat('Call:\n', toString(afunction(a ~ b, dataframe)))`?

Comment: Yeah! But that seems to call the function repeatedly.

Comment: @OLGJ See update and try `match.call()`.